# DeActivate Portal User by himself using apex class

Tags: apex

Need Help on **"how to deactivate the Customer portal user using apex**".

Currently we trying to deactivate the portal user with portal user sessionId. for this we are getting Exception as follows

> @ EXCEPTION_THROWN|[183]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 00511000000QnNCAA0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot de-activate self: Active: [IsActive]

i am using the code below for deactivate the portal user

```
         User u = [select Id, IsActive, IsPortalEnabled from User where Id =: temp];

         u.IsActive = false;

         IsPortalEnabled = false;

         update u;
```

with the same user session Id. how to do this???

Thanks

Sathish

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit convoluted, but could work.  The users won't be deactivated immediately, but they will be deactivated (eventually) in response to their own action.  (Thanks to @sfdcfox for helping design this approach.)

1. Put a custom field on User called something like `Deactivate_Me__c`
2. Write a `Schedulable` class that checks for any portal user accounts with the `Deactivate_Me__c` flag set, and deactivates them.
3. Schedule the apex job to run on a schedule that makes sense for you, making sure to schedule the job as an admin user.
4. If you need *something* to happen immediately, it may be possible to write a trigger that would change the user's profile to a more restrictive profile (but I haven't checked that).  The second profile could have no record access and all tabs hidden except one that says "Your account is pending deactivation."

Of course, the deeper question is what you're trying to accomplish with this workflow.  Why does a user want to deactivate their own account?  If they do it by accident, how do they fix their error?  Etc.

Comment: That would probably only work if the workflow user was not the user who triggered the workflow event... because even in system code, you can't deactivate yourself.

Comment: Just because you're running in system code doesn't mean that "it's no longer tied to the user making the request." It only means that sharing may not be enabled; you're actually assuming that the `@future` method is also stored in a class "without sharing".

Comment: Good point @fox.  I hadn't actually tried this (that's probably clear).  With your modifications, do you think it would work, or should I delete this answer?

Comment: You were close, though; your idea gave me one of my own that may work. Have the `Deactivate_Me__c` field, like here, but instead have a scheduled class that "sweeps" users every once in a while and deactivates them. Have the sweeper scheduled by a system administrator.

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer, or should I update mine?

Comment: You can go for it. My answer would have been a derivative of yours anyways.